# how i can retrieve spatial data (point) from msql database with cakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, geospatial, cakephp-3.0

I have the table with next structure:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coordinates` point NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

In PointsTable.php something like that:

---

```
public function beforeSave( $event,  $entity,  $options) {     
     $entity->coordinates = new QueryExpression('GeomFromText(\'POINT(' . $entity['latitude'] . " " . $entity['longitude'] . ')\')');
}
```

---

So, I don't understand, how to retrieve lat, lon coordinates  to view file from coordinates filed.

Comment: have you solved your problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Nichs  Same Problem. How retrieve data from DB ...